# regex in sqlite without extra loaded libraries

Tags: linux, sqlite

I connect on an embedded device that has SQLite, but it has the default regex support, not anything extra over it.
In this default regex support, **I want to match columns that start with 'B' or 'AA'.**

(with grep this works: `grep -P "^(B|AA)" myfile.txt`)

but in SQLite something like

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table1 WHERE (col2 REGEXP 'AA' OR col2 REGEXP 'B');
```

does not work.

Does anybody know why?
I know it's default regex engine, but simple regex..

Comment: Why use regexp when you have a really small number of literal strings?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's(more aptly ***[`SQLite3`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp)***) built-in `REGEXP` operator does not support the same syntax as grep's `-P` option. However, you can achieve your requirement in a slightely different way:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table1 WHERE (col2 REGEXP '^(B|AA)' OR col2 GLOB 'BA*');
```

In the above query:

- **`col2 REGEXP '^(B|AA)'`**- matches columns that start with `B` or `AA` using POSIX regular expressions.
- **`col2 GLOB 'BA*'`** - matches columns that start with `BA` using glob patterns.

***[CODE DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/5uIkfDMXn6)***

Comment: thanks for de detailed answer and code demo.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the details.

The demo made me realize the problem is not the limited regex support
in SQLite; I mean the regex worked in your case but not in my case.
Something like
SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table1 WHERE (col2 REGEXP 'AB');
was not working for me, but then I saw that you defined your column type
as TEXT, and in my case I have BLOB and the content is made of UTF-16 chars.

I think this is where REGEXP is confused, it expects regular characters.
I managed to match a pattern like 'first char is A, second char is B' with
**SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table1 WHERE SUBSTR(col2, 1, 2) = X'0041' AND SUBSTR(col2, 3, 2) = X'0042';**

maybe I'll work around this idea.